# CHEF provisioning: SystemStackError: stack level too deep

Tags: ruby, docker, chef-infra, knife

I'm making a node provisioner with [CHEF](https://www.chef.io/), I want to create and configure Docker containers inside it.

Currently I get a CHEF node with Chefdk and chef-provisioner-docker, but when I trigger the recipe to create containers (machine) I get a `Stack level too deep` withc I dont understand why.

Stacktrace:

```
[2016-02-16T11:12:21-05:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
[2016-02-16T11:12:21-05:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.5.1 ***
[2016-02-16T11:12:21-05:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 2456
[2016-02-16T11:12:23-05:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[dockerice], recipe[provisioning]]
[2016-02-16T11:12:23-05:00] INFO: Run List expands to [dockerice, provisioning]
[2016-02-16T11:12:23-05:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for provisioner-1
[2016-02-16T11:12:23-05:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2016-02-16T11:12:23-05:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2016-02-16T11:12:24-05:00] INFO: Loading cookbooks [dockerice@0.1.0, docker@2.4.16, compat_resource@12.7.1, provisioning@0.1.0]
[2016-02-16T11:12:24-05:00] INFO: Processing docker_service[default] action create (dockerice::default line 10)
[2016-02-16T11:12:24-05:00] INFO: Processing docker_installation_script[default] action create (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/docker/libraries/docker_service.rb line 53)
[2016-02-16T11:12:24-05:00] INFO: Processing apt_package[curl] action install (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/docker/libraries/docker_installation_script.rb line 35)
[2016-02-16T11:12:24-05:00] INFO: Processing execute[install docker] action run (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/docker/libraries/docker_installation_script.rb line 39)
[2016-02-16T11:12:24-05:00] INFO: Processing docker_service[default] action start (dockerice::default line 10)
[2016-02-16T11:12:24-05:00] INFO: Processing docker_service_manager_systemd[default] action start (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/docker/libraries/docker_service.rb line 71)
[2016-02-16T11:12:25-05:00] WARN: Default value false is invalid for property tls_ca_cert of resource . In Chef 13 this will become an error: Property tls_ca_cert must be one of: String, nil!  You passed false.. at /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/compat_resource/files/lib/chef_compat/monkeypatches/chef.rb:20:in `log_deprecation'
[2016-02-16T11:12:25-05:00] INFO: Processing directory[/usr/libexec] action create (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/docker/libraries/docker_service_manager_systemd.rb line 23)
[2016-02-16T11:12:25-05:00] INFO: Processing template[/usr/libexec/docker-wait-ready] action create (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/docker/libraries/docker_service_manager_systemd.rb line 32)
[2016-02-16T11:12:25-05:00] INFO: Processing template[/lib/systemd/system/docker.service] action create (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/docker/libraries/docker_service_manager_systemd.rb line 46)
[2016-02-16T11:12:25-05:00] INFO: Processing file[/etc/docker-firstconverge] action create (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/docker/libraries/docker_service_manager_systemd.rb line 63)
[2016-02-16T11:12:25-05:00] INFO: Processing execute[systemctl daemon-reload] action nothing (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/docker/libraries/docker_service_manager_systemd.rb line 68)
[2016-02-16T11:12:25-05:00] INFO: Processing template[/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/docker.conf] action create (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/docker/libraries/docker_service_manager_systemd.rb line 74)
[2016-02-16T11:12:25-05:00] INFO: Processing service[docker] action enable (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/docker/libraries/docker_service_manager_systemd.rb line 85)
[2016-02-16T11:12:25-05:00] INFO: Processing service[docker] action start (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/docker/libraries/docker_service_manager_systemd.rb line 85)
[2016-02-16T11:12:25-05:00] INFO: Processing machine[contenedor] action converge (provisioning::default line 12)
[2016-02-16T11:12:25-05:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Object Not Found: error
[2016-02-16T11:12:25-05:00] WARN: chef_environment nil currently does not overwrite the value of chef_environment. This will change in Chef 13, and the value will be set to nil instead. Please change your code to explicitly accept nil using "property :chef_environment, [MyType, nil]", or stop setting this value to nil. at /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/compat_resource/files/lib/chef_compat/monkeypatches/chef.rb:20:in `log_deprecation' at /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/event_dispatch/dispatcher.rb:38:in `call'
[0m
================================================================================[0m
[31mError executing action `converge` on resource 'machine[contenedor]'[0m
================================================================================[0m

[0mSystemStackError[0m
----------------[0m
stack level too deep[0m

[0mCookbook Trace:[0m
---------------[0m
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/docker/files/default/vendor/gems/excon-0.45.4/lib/excon/headers.rb:33[0m

[0mResource Declaration:[0m
---------------------[0m
# In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/provisioning/recipes/default.rb
[0m
[0m 12: machine 'contenedor' do
[0m 13:     machine_options :docker_options => {
[0m 14:       :base_image => {
[0m 15:           :name => 'ubuntu',
[0m 16:           :repository => 'ubuntu',
[0m 17:           :tag => '14.04'
[0m 18:       },
[0m 19:       :command => '/usr/sbin/sshd -p 8022 -D',
[0m 20:     }
[0m 21: end
[0m
[0mCompiled Resource:[0m
------------------[0m
# Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/provisioning/recipes/default.rb:12:in `from_file'
[0m
[0mmachine("contenedor") do
[0m  action [:converge]
[0m  retries 0
[0m  retry_delay 2
[0m  default_guard_interpreter :default
[0m  chef_server {:chef_server_url=>"https://api.chef.io/organizations/aramirez", :options=>{:client_name=>"provisioner-1", :signing_key_filename=>"/etc/chef/client.pem", :api_version=>"0"}}
[0m  driver "docker"
[0m  machine_options {:docker_options=>{:base_image=>{:name=>"ubuntu", :repository=>"ubuntu", :tag=>"14.04"}, :command=>"/usr/sbin/sshd -p 8022 -D"}}
[0m  declared_type :machine
[0m  cookbook_name "provisioning"
[0m  recipe_name "default"
[0mend
[0m
[0m[2016-02-16T11:12:25-05:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[2016-02-16T11:12:25-05:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2016-02-16T11:12:25-05:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2016-02-16T11:12:25-05:00] INFO: Sending resource update report (run-id: 58ed0337-8487-4d72-8c28-c11e9c57551d)
[2016-02-16T11:12:26-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-02-16T11:12:26-05:00] ERROR: machine[contenedor] (provisioning::default line 12) had an error: SystemStackError: stack level too deep
[2016-02-16T11:12:26-05:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

How can I solve it to able to create docker containers in a provisioner node?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Chef-provisioning is alpha-level code, and the docker driver probably even more so. You are better off filing a GitHub issue on the relevant project because very few people have used either and you want a direct conduit to those that have.